# For-Loop doesn't finish without error message

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I have this `for`-loop:

```
y1 = 0; y2 = 3264; x1 = 0; x2 = 4928; uc = 1; vc = 1; scale = 1;

for (var y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
    for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
        sumR = 0;
        sumG = 0;
        sumB = 0;
        i = 0;

        for (var v = -vc; v <= vc; v++) {
            for (var u = -uc; u <= uc; u++) {
                if (kernel[i] != 0) {
                    var tempX = x + u < 0 ? 0 : x + u;
                    var tempY = y + v < 0 ? 0 : y + v;
                    tempX = tempX >= width ? width - 1 : tempX;
                    tempY = tempY >= height ? height - 1 : tempY;

                    sumR += pixels.data[((tempY * (pixels.width*4)) + (tempX * 4)) + 0] * kernel[i];
                    sumG += pixels.data[((tempY * (pixels.width*4)) + (tempX * 4)) + 1] * kernel[i];
                    sumB += pixels.data[((tempY * (pixels.width*4)) + (tempX * 4)) + 2] * kernel[i];
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        tempArray.push(sumR * scale, sumG * scale, sumB * scale, 255);
    }
    console.log(y + "|" + y2);
}
```

So basically it's about image processing, the loop stops at y = 3115 without any error, everything after the loop isn't computed it just "crashes" there. Do you guys have any ideas how this could happen? Can there be a problem with memory?

UPDATE: I think I made this abit unclear: if I use this algorithm for a image with size y2 = 1000 and x2 = 1000 everything is working fine. But if the images get bigger it just stopps working, there is no errormessage in the console!

Comment: What do you mean it "crashes"? Is there any information in the console?

Comment: What is the value of x2, vc and uc when the loop starts

Comment: You have a syntax error in teh code, at the end of the first line: `uc + vc = 1;`.

Comment: I updated the question a bit to make it clearer --> there is now error in the console, it just stopps looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally I found the problem,

I initialized the array this way: `var tempArray = [];` above the for-loops, next step was that I tried to initialize it this way : `var tempArray = new Array(width * height * 4)`

The browser just stopped at that position now and didn't even enter the for-loops. So I guess the Array is just to big to create.

Solution: I am using a Typed Array now and everything is working:

```
var tempArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

- `uc + vc = 1;` is a invalid statement,
- `uc` and `vc` don't seem to be defined anywhere,
- `scale` isn't defined anywhere.
- The second `x1` here should probably be `x2`:

  ```
  x1 = 0; x1 = 4928;
  //Should probably be:
  x1 = 0; x2 = 4928;
  ```

<strike>This pretty much comes down to: *"debug your code".*</strike>

Comment: I am sorry, that was just a copy and paste mistake! I updated the question.

Comment: I see.
Can you log the values of `sumR, sumG, sumB`? (After the loop's "crashed", so you'll have to declare the vars before the first `for`-loop) And what's the value of `scale`?

Comment: sumR, sumG, sumB are the expected results. The kernel is [0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0].

Comment: Thos expected results being what?

Comment: From -1024 to 1024, scale = 1

Comment: uc and vc are both 1 (kernel radius)
as there are no errors and it's working with smaller images I think the syntax should be right, but what else could be the problem?

Comment: I've got no clue. If the pixel-index you're calculating were out of bounds, it'd throw an error, so that's not it, either...

Comment: right I am clamping them to 0 and 255 now, but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Okay if you are interested I finally found the problem

Comment: @kaljak, what was it? Ah, I see your answer.